# Unable to add EKS cluster to ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, argocd

Command:

```
argocd cluster add <cluster_context> -y
```

Output:

```
INFO[0001] ServiceAccount "argocd-manager" already exists in namespace "kube-system"
INFO[0002] ClusterRole "argocd-manager-role" updated
INFO[0003] ClusterRoleBinding "argocd-manager-role-binding" updated
FATA[0036] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.23.x.x:443: i/o timeout**
```

Expected Output:

```
INFO[0002] ServiceAccount "argocd-manager" created in namespace "kube-system"
INFO[0003] ClusterRole "argocd-manager-role" created
INFO[0003] ClusterRoleBinding "argocd-manager-role-binding" created
Cluster 'https://xxxxxxxxx.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com' added
```

EKS cluster endpoint is public and private.
Allowed IP list contains my machine IP.

Comment: If your argoCD machine is in the same network with your cluster, they will not communicate publicly, can you check whether your argo machine's security group is allowed in EKS control plane security group or not?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun would you mind elaborating?